# How to hook in a login rate limiter for Grails Spring Security without hitting the database?

Tags: grails, spring-security, rate-limiting

I would like to add a rate limiter that intercepts login attempts before any checks are done against the database.  IP address and username will both need to be available to the business logic of this limiter.  The limiter would allow the attempt to proceed normally if rate isn't exceeded, but not if it failed (it should return an error to the user, or allow me to redirect the user, without any database hit for login attempt).

Where is the correct point to hook this in?  Normally a grails filter would work for this type of thing, but it appears given my reading that all the Spring Security logic happens before any grails filters fire.

*Note:* this question is not about how to implement the rate limiter logic, but exactly where and how to hook it into Grails Spring Security

Answer (score 0):

In springsecurity you can add your own provider. It requires to implement org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider

add it as a spring bean (resources.groovy) and add it as a provider: 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['MutipleAttemptIntercepterProvider']

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on how implementing your own provider can delegate to the existing one if the rate is not exceeded.  Code example?

Comment: AuthenticationProvider has a method authenticate(Authentication authentication). if it returns null it will continue to the next provider.
@see: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.1.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html#authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)